# Three js in a class

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to set all the necessary functionality into one class in order to create a simple three.js scene with a cube. I don't get any errors, but the scene stays black when I open it in the browser.
Here is my code:

```
class SceneInit {

    constructor(fov = 45,camera,scene,controls,renderer)
    {
        this.camera = camera;
        this.scene = scene;
        this.controls = controls;
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.fov = fov;

    }



    initScene() {
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(this.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        this.camera.position.z = 15;

        this.controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( this.camera );
        //this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.renderScene);

        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //specify a canvas which is already created in the HTML file and tagged by an id        //aliasing enabled
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myThreeJsCanvas') , antialias: true});
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


        //ambient light which is for the whole scene
        let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.7);
        ambientLight.castShadow = false;
        this.scene.add(ambientLight);

        //spot light which is illuminating the chart directly
        let spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.55);
        spotLight.castShadow = true;
        spotLight.position.set(0,40,10);
        this.scene.add(spotLight);


        //if window resizes
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize, false);
    }


    animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );
        this.render();
        this.controls.update();
    }


    render(){
        this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
    }


    onWindowResize() {
    this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

}
```

And then I try to instantiate a new object and add an object to the scene. When I try to print the children of the scene, it returns me the right objects, but as I mentioned before the scene stays black. Only the renderer window is getting drawed in the browser.

```
let test = new SceneInit(45);
test.initScene();
test.animate();


let geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

test.scene.add(mesh);
console.log(test.scene.children); //returns 3 objects (ambientLight, spotLight, mesh)
```

Comment: Have you tried making your camera _lookAt_ the correct position? Currently  you are moving it into the z-axis and I think it might be looking into the void further down the z-axis. Try `test.camera.lookAt( mesh.position )` or `test.camera.lookAt( test.scene.position )`. Something I _have_ learned over time, however, is that this is really not how you are intended to use this. By wrapping renderers etc.. inside a class you are losing a lot of flexibility. The code was not intended to be used like this, and its easier if you use global declarations (every renderer uses memory!)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it didn't worked!
The reason why I am putting it into a class is because I will make a small library which will consist of multiple javascript files representing various charts. And with this approach I can make this code reusable => cleaner code!

Comment: Cleaner code !== Better Code, though! (I say this mostly because of how memory intesive this stuff can be, so having _one_ renderer is better than having two. You could seperate them using scenes... but then we are back to using vanilla threeJS as intended). Regarding your problem, first I would check if its rendering at all. Simply add a giant, wireframe sphere to your main scene and see if it shows up. After that, place some different colored cubes in different directions and find out which you are seeing etc... It takes a while but it will help you figure it out.

Comment: Thats right, it's not always better code, but as I mentioned before, I have to use this approach because I want it and I have to fulfill it for the project.
I will try to put some more objects into the scene and maybe also some with a bigger size!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Anyhow, disregarding the structure, `THREE.SpotLight` is quirky - you need it to `lookAt` something as well, and preferably _before_ adding it to the scene. That might be why things are invisible. Also, your box is 200x200x200, with a _basic_ Basic Material. This means that your camera is probably _inside_ your box, meaning it will try to film the backsides of your box's sides. But by default, backsides are hidden. Again, try with `wireframe` - this works wherever your camera is resided. Also, try calling your `test.render()` _after_ adding your box?

Comment: I have tried to implement the old version where I called all the functions in one file without any class...I added the BoxGeometry and it also stays black! 
So something with the BoxGeometry is wrong.
Btw can you post an example with a wireframe?

Comment: To use a wireframe, pass the correct options when constructing a material: `let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true});`. Wireframes do not adhere to front/backface visibilities, so they should always be visible as long as the camera is pointing at a vertex.

Comment: @somethinghere Thank you for your answer! You helped me a lot!
I have posted the answer below!
I will upvote your comment!

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

The problem in the code was that the BoxGeometry was too big and the camera was inside the box. With the clipping set to 1 it wouldn't even render it.
So the solution is to set a smaller BoxGeometry. or to move the camera away!

Comment: The solutions is not actually to set a smaller box, its to move the box _away_ from the camera. Three.js, by default, will only show faces you are looking at from the front (aka, faces where the vertices it consists of are counter-clockwise according the the camera position)

Comment: Edited the answer!